# how can i upgrade my libyaml version

Tags: ruby, libyaml

i installed ruby by homebrew,how can i upgrade my libyaml version。 i flowed this [reference](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/03/29/heap-overflow-in-yaml-uri-escape-parsing-cve-2014-2525/)

this is my osx operation：

```
➜  ~  ruby -rpsych -e 'p Psych.libyaml_version' 
[0, 1, 4]
➜  ~  ls /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.6 
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json README               lib
LICENSE              include
➜  ~  ./configure --with-yaml-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.6
zsh: no such file or directory: ./configure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you really wanted to recompile ruby, didn’t you? I would not recommend you to go with recompilation until you have a strong understanding on what `configure` script is at least.

Please re-read the reference accurately and follow the appropriate recommendation:

> Users without a system libyaml rely on the embedded libyaml and are recommended to update psych to 2.0.5 which vendors libyaml 0.1.6:

```
$ gem install psych
```

> or, update your Ruby to 2.0.0-p481, 2.1.2 or newer.

Comment: rvm install 2.0.0-p481